# Loop to pull every ID into dataframe from API in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I need a hand please!

I have multiple datasets I need to pull from an API. Each one has it's on ID on the end of the API url, but when I use a for loop it only pulls data from the last ID I listed instead of all of them.

*This is what I tried.*
For example:

```
ids <- c("101", "252", "595")

for(i in ids){
url <- paste0("example/api/url/", i, "/")
api_pull <- GET(url)
table = fromJSON(rawToChar(api_pull$content))
table <- as.data.frame(table$data)
}

View(table)
```

**MY ISSUE: When I use this loop it only downloads the final ID "595", how can I change it to download each ID and put them into one dataframe?**

*Outside of this example I have about 400 ID's to download which I don't want to do individually..*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting your `table` variable every time. Try initializing it once, and then rbind new records to it. Here's an example to show you what is going wrong:

```
#Imaginary data source: 
source_data <- data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 3), 
                          value = c("a", "b", "c"))
#Your IDs:
ids <- c(1, 2, 3)

#Overwriting the table data frame: 
for (i in ids) {
  table <- source_data[source_data$id == i, ]
}

#Note that only the last record is present: 
print(table)
#>   id value
#> 3  3     c

#Working example:
table <- data.frame(id = numeric(), 
                    value = character())

for (i in ids) {
  table <- rbind(table, source_data[source_data$id == i, ])
}

#Note that all records are present:
print(table)
#>   id value
#> 1  1     a
#> 2  2     b
#> 3  3     c
```

Comment: That's perfect, thank you very much and for a fast respose.

Comment: This is a good answer. I should only advise against this method for growing the table if `ids` is a long vector - could get very inefficient. initializing the table with `data.frame(id = numeric(length(ids)), value = character(length(ids))` and assign inside the loop with `{table[i] <- source_data ..... ` looks a bit better